# value of $index in the loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have an `<input>` element with a `ng-repeat` directive.

```
  <input ng-repeat="table in tables track by $index" type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="user.$index">
```

I want the value of `$index` in the loop , it's possible.

Comment: you need to display or you need to make dynamic html element?

Comment: `ng-model="user[$index]"` is this? BTW what is user? can you post that array?

Comment: "user[$index]" doesnt work

Comment: You can just use `{{$index}}`

Answer (score 2):

you show it like this:

```
{{$index}}
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/TRoZZ7L31LjdSOiPkrip?p=preview):

```
  <ul class="example-animate-container">
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results">
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
    </li>
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-if="results.length == 0">
      <strong>No results found...</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$index` in **[AngularJS Expresion](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)**.

Eg.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Expression</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var mod = angular.module('myApp', []);
      mod.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope){
        $scope.tables = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'];
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input ng-repeat="table in tables track by $index" type="text" name="lastName" value="{{$index}}">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
     
  <form>
   <div ng-repeat="table  in tables  track by $index" >
    <input ="text" name="name"><br>
      </div>     
  </form>          

  <button type="button" ng-click="addtable()">
    +
  </button>
  {{tables}}
</div>    


  <script type="text/javascript">
 
  var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
  app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
     
   $scope.tables=[""];
   $scope.addtable = function() {
        
             $scope.tables.push(" ");
   }; 
 
    });  
 </script> `

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<input ng-repeat="table in tables track by $index" type="text" name="lastName" value="{{$index}}">
```

Comment: That should be `$index` not `index`.